# Caret not working in batch file, works in Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I use this script to get the results of a url:

```
@Echo off
For /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'powershell -NonI -NoP -C "(Invoke-Webrequest "%~1").content"'
) Do set Line=%%A
```

I can call it in a command prompt window like this:

```
 WebResponse.cmd "http://websiteremoved.com/teststat.php?username^=%friend1%"
```

I need to use the caret (`^`) to cancel out the Equal sign. However when I run that same line of code in my batch file it does not work. According to the test, %~1 is set to `"http://websiteremoved.com/teststat.php?username^=Lukaka"` but the powershell portion returns this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Lukaka'. [] http://websiteremoved.com/teststat.php?username^=Lukaka 
At line:1 char:2 [] http://websiteremoved.com/teststat.php?username^=Lukaka 
+ (Invoke-Webrequest http://websiteremoved.com/teststat.p ... [] http://websiteremoved.com/teststat.php?username^=Lukaka 
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [] http://websiteremoved.com/teststat.php?username^=Lukaka 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException [] http://websiteremoved.com/teststat.php?username^=Lukaka 
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand [] http://websiteremoved.com/teststat.php?username^=Lukaka
```

Any ideas as to why it is doing this? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You got me wrong last time, I said either quote **or** escape, not both.

Comment: Why use `cmd.exe` at all? Just run the command you want to run directly from the PowerShell prompt.

Comment: Depends on how much memory you have available. `cmd.exe 0.4MB` compared to `PowerShell 32MB`. (80 times more memory required just to have powershell open) Of course if you have 4G free -- who cares...

Comment: Spinning up a copy of `powershell.exe` just to run one command is (to put it mildly) quite inefficient. If you need PowerShell, then use it and leave it open. (Then you're not inefficiently spinning up new copies, because it's already open.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Im running this from a batch file. the running of it from cmd.exe was just to test it.

Comment: @LotPings The quotes seem to make no difference

Comment: Don't use a batch file to begin with. Run the command directly from PowerShell, or use a PowerShell script.

Comment: I don't know powershell. How could I do this while placing the %friend1% variable into the powershell script from the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

The way I was doing it was inefficient. I am closing this question. I am working on a different version of a new script here: [Add Multiple URLs to this Powershell Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924385/add-multiple-urls-to-this-powershell-script) which is related.