# Add Multiple URLs to this PowerShell Script?

Tags: powershell, url, input, output

I am using a script to call URLs, get the output, and save the output to a text file. It all works great. However, when I need to call multiple URLs in succession it causes CPU spikes because it is starting/stopping `powershell.exe` so many times. Is there a whay I could use a `for each` technique for each URL while still saving the output? Here is my script:

```
$content = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\urls.txt

echo "Testing for $content"

(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$content").Content |
    Out-File -FilePath "$PSScriptRoot\out.txt"

$status = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\out.txt
```

Note that the two `echo` are just for debugging purposes, don't really matter.

Comment: You mean something like `Get-Content urls.txt | ForEach-Object { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ | Select-Object -Expand Content }`?

Comment: yup! That is what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this Something that you wanted to do?

```
$contents = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\urls.txt
foreach($content in $contents){
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$content").Content |Out-File -FilePath $PSScriptRoot\out.txt -Append
}
```

I Wrote a urls.txt with 7-8 urls,And it worked fine for me.

Comment: aha I was missing the `{  }` and the `-Append`. Perfect my friend!

Comment: Can't Chetan Not enough rep! sry.

Comment: Cool.no problem! Get back when you have rep,Cheers